# How do I centre points inside a cv2.rectangle drawn in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

So I am using the following code to normalise points and draw them inside a cv2.square [image]
[image]

But as you noticed there is more space on the left and what i would like to do is to place the points in the centre

Here is my code, points array is shorter

```
points = np.array([        
    [0.8252923243905792, 0.23409826375167195], [0.835683753646597, 0.2185883280832016], [0.8131540844750428, 0.21904862499113367], [0.8506741192799976, 0.2279991219170517], 
    [0.7959142481709739, 0.22725381616179272], [0.8733570624656342, 0.3256920048853457],[0.7652207837892534, 0.3239122878098148], [0.893097550288673, 0.44273291363944955], 
    [0.7346131146711571, 0.4430594635999311], [0.902709244982588, 0.5343829401117663], [0.8520378940615836, 0.543215423861057], [0.7842126810888624, 0.5430821914771806], 
    [0.8496391467917583, 0.7170072127563635], [0.7934480818135997, 0.7157067918591926],[0.8415470663986131, 0.8790693270711738], [0.7969306654944098, 0.8786970205344115], 
    [0.8191112469834433, 0.32444646417244244]], np.float64)
 
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (rect[0], rect[1]), (rect[2], rect[3]), (255, 0, 255), 2)
    
    w = rect[2] - rect[0]
    h = rect[3] - rect[1]

    for x, y in points:
        
        x = (x * w) + rect[0]
        y = (y * h) + rect[1]

        cv2.circle(frame,(int(x),int(y)),2,(255, 0, 0),2)

        a = [x,y]
```

Comment: Rough idea: calculate the mean of evenly spaced points along the outer regions. The mean will be the center of the rectangle/square. Use it to form the width and height of your choice. Its easier said then done :)

Comment: How do i picked up outer points?

Comment: "How do i picked up outer points?" - [Convex Hull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) will give you the points on the boundary.

Comment: maybe you should calculate center point for your data `(max_x + min_x)//2` and `(max_y + min_y)//2` and later calculate difference between this center and center of rectangle to get offset - `offset_x = center_x - rect_center_x` and later add this `offset` to all points to move them to center of rectangle. OR substract from rect points to move rect to center of data.

Comment: if you use points with values `0...1` then you could use `(0.5, 0.5)` as center of rect and calculate offset between center of all poins and `(0.5, 0.5)` to calculate offset which you have to add before you calculate `(x+offset_x) * w`